# Bigquery regex extract digits after multiple spaces

Tags: regex, google-bigquery

Could you please help using regexp_extract digits from the following example lines:

1. 11BARIIOTA0292DEBORAH (space) OLLA (space) JENNY (long-multiple spaces)                                                  0000001242202173171 (space)
2. 11SBADIOTA0300MICHELLE (space) MARGARETE (long-multiple spaces)                                                     0040170225 (space)
3. 11NITYIOTA0300SYAHLA (space) RYAN (long-multiple spaces)                                                        613821914423 (space)

Into:

1. 0000001642202173171
2. 0040170225
3. 613821914423

fyi: long-multiple space is around 40-50 spaces

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider below approach

```
select array_reverse(split(trim(col_name), ' '))[offset(0)]
from your_table
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: what is offset mean? btw, this works very well ty

Comment: Check out [OFFSET and ORDINAL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/array_functions#offset_and_ordinal)

Answer (score 2):

For lines that terminate with 1-*or*-more spaces, and 'long-multiple-space' is 40-50 spaces.
Here's some different match expressions, depending on your needs...

Match: `^.* {40,50}(\d+) +$`
Replace: Group1

Match: `^[A-Z\d]+(?: [A-Z]+){1,2} {40,50}(\d+) +$`
Replace: Group1

With regexp_extract, I *think* the syntax looks more like...
`regexp_extract(filename,'^.* {40,50}(\d+) +$', 1)`
`regexp_extract(filename,'^[A-Z\d]+(?: [A-Z]+){1,2} {40,50}(\d+) +$', 1)`

The {1,2} is what matches either 1-*or*-2 names (like OLLA and JENNY on Line1).
Use {1,9} to match anywhere from 1-9 of those space-separated names.
(same thing with {40,50} for the 'long-multiple-spaces')

Comment: when names with Capitalized then i can add like (?: [a-zA-Z]+) yes?

Comment: @Auffan Adding a-z would also match lowercase, but the top expression should suffice. I only included the lower expression incase you needed to be very specific. If needing to be even more specific, you could include include IOTA into the expression, assuming its in all of your strings.

Answer (score 0):

you can transform your string to simple space separated values then extract numerical values using regexp_extract on top of that resultant string.

```
select REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE("11BARIIOTA0292DEBORAH                  OLLA  JENNY                                                                                             0000001242202173171","  ",""),'[^0-9 ]','');
```